# Error: Externally managed Environment,PIP

Tags: linux, python, arch-linux, pip

I am having this error while installing a package using PIP, How to fix it?

```
[xyro@arch ~]$ pip install flask
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try 'pacman -S
    python-xyz', where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Arch-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using 'python -m venv path/to/venv'.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Arch packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use 'pipx install xyz', which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have python-pipx
    installed via pacman.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
[xyro@arch ~]$
```

Comment: Have you tried as it suggests using `pacman -S python-flask`? Otherwise it clearly suggests another option using a virtual environment and even gives you instruction on how to set it up and use `pipx` instead of `pip`.

Comment: yeah I have tried it and it works but I can install the requirements.txt files with that and pipx also do not support the command `pipx install -r requirements.txt`, I gotta install all the packages manually, Do you know how can I use the -r command in `pacman -S python-flask`?

Answer (score 1):

As the instructions suggest, you'll be able to install non-Arch packaged services by creating a virtual environment. This also works if you try to install multiple packages from a `requirements.txt` file. So you need to run the following:

```py
python3 -m venv .venv
```

This creates a `.venv` folder for your packages locally.

```py
source .venv/bin/activate
```

And this activates your Python virtual environment.

Now you can run `pip install -r requirements.txt` or `pip install <package-name>`. This is simply a safer way of installing packages in your system.